# Open notification center with key combo

Tags: wingpanel

I would like to open notifications with key combo(sorta like gnome3 and windows do),but i dont know how to trigger it.

If anyone has idea,Id be more then happy to hear it!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on elementary 5.0 Juno: user@workstation:~$ switchboard settings://notifications switchboard: Command not found. user@workstation:~$

Comment: Hi Riker. Here's an answer that applies to Juno: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/18017/keyboard-to-show-expland-all-notifications/18025#18025

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keyboard to show/expland all notifications](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/18017/keyboard-to-show-expland-all-notifications)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command in terminal is: switchboard settings://notifications

If you enter this command in the Keyboard/Shortcuts as a new shortcut and enter an 'accelerator' (a key combination) this should work.

See:
[image: Ctrl-F12 as a shortcut to the notifications center]

Comment: This answer is no longer valid in elementary Juno. Here is a more current answer: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/18017/keyboard-to-show-expland-all-notifications