# Keyboard to show/expland all notifications

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, notifications

Is there a way to set a keyboard shortcut to show all notifications, i.e. expand the notification bell icon to show all missed notifications.

Right now I have to click the bell icon to show all notifications. I would like to be able to do it through the keyboard as well.

I've checked in the keyboard shortcut settings but I couldn't find an action.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I looked around in the Elementary Keyboard Shortcuts and didn't find anything. Fortunately, this is still possible. The command line to run to show notifications is this:

```
wingpanel -o messages
```

If you open up a terminal and run that, it should work.

With that in mind, you can go into System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts. From there, select Custom and add a new shortcut (the plus icon at the very bottom). I've highlighted the added command-line shortcut in this screenshot. (You can ignore the other custom keyboard shortcuts I've added):

[image: Screenshot of settings showing keyboard shortcut]

Comment: Thanks so much! That fixed it for me. 
I used
`wingpanel -t messages` 
to quickly be able to toggle between the shown and hidden states.

Answer (score -1):

I looked around in the Elementary Keyboard Shortcuts and didn't find anything. Fortunately, this is still possible. The command line to run to show notifications is this:

wingpanel -o messages
If you open up a terminal and run that, it should work.

With that in mind, you can go into System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts. From there, select Custom and add a new shortcut (the plus icon at the very bottom). I've highlighted the added command-line shortcut in this screenshot. (You can ignore the other custom keyboard shortcuts I've added):

Screenshot of settings showing keyboard shortcut